# Is there a script to create azure custom alerts format and any log analytics query to get azure VM status

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, dashboard, azure-log-analytics

I have below two questions can someone help on them.

1.Is there a script or a way to create custom alert format for azure alerts?

2.Is there a way to pin all the azure VM status to dashboard?

Comment: What's your first question?

Comment: Hello, can you please add a comment to answer my question?

Comment: if i create any alert from log analytics , i will receive and email for my alerts. But i would like to edit some fields in that email that i received for the alert and customize it. How can i edit and change the mail format that i receive for my alerts.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding #1, the feature to customize or configure alert email format is currently not supported. If interested, I suggest you to raise your feedback / feature request [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/267889-log-analytics) in UserVoice / feedback forum. Responsible product / feature team would triage / start checking feasibility and would prioritize the feedback.

Regarding #2, If 'status' is meant as 'PowerState' (i.e., status of VM whether it is running, deallocated, etc.) or if it's meant as 'StatusCode' (i.e., ok, etc.) or if it's meant as 'ProvisioningState' (i.e., succeeded, etc.) then I don't think we have straight-forward way for it so that we can ingest that particular data directly to dashboard but said that, you may just leverage 'Heartbeat' Log Analytics Kusto table at first place and create a custom view as dashboard using [view designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/view-designer) but as views in Azure Monitor are being phased out and replaced with [workbooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/workbooks-overview) so I suggest leveraging these workbooks now.

If not, you may leverage a new feature called as [Azure Monitor for VMs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/vminsights-overview) which basically helps to analyze the performance and health of your Windows and Linux VMs, and monitor their processes and dependencies on other resources and external processes. Here again, you can create interactive reports Azure Monitor for VMs with [VM insights workbooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/vminsights-workbooks).